# Make Xcode NOT auto scroll to (near) the bottom of the debug console when new lines are output

Tags: xcode9

(This is with iOS if it matters)

This seems to be a new problem with Xcode 9.  One I did not have in Xcode 8.   If I am looking at debug output in Xcode's debug console, and I have purposefully scrolled to a line near the top or middle, when the app outputs a new line (say a ping outputs an NSLog with some diagnostic info), the app leaves where I was looking, and jumps down to the bottom, or close to the bottom (I've noticed that it is not always the absolute bottom).  This is very annoying f I am trying to read through debug output in the app that is not the very end of the output in the debug window.

I did not have this issue with Xcode 8.   Is there a way to change this behavior?  I did not find any options in the Xcode 9 app preferences.

This problem remains a problem after upgrading Xcode to 9.2

Comment: Still a problem in Xcode 10. Annoying me too.

Answer (score 3):

Finally found a way to prevent autoscrolling on further output - move the scroll bar to anywhere except the bottom.

EDIT: and then click in the console output.

Comment: I'll try this.  I think I did try it in Xcode 9.x (which I am still on) and it still did it but I could be mis-remembering.  Thanks.   I'll report back on my tests when I have a chance.